# create dynamic path to server.database.table in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I am trying to dynamically create tables. Tables from one database (@sourcedatabase) are used to create tables in another (@targetdatabase).

This works fine when I explicitly name the databases. However, I would like them to be dynamic, as in the following example. I have read a lot about that and I am fine using things like

```
set @sql = 'DROP TABLE ' + @targetdatabase + '.' + @SomeNAME 
execute (@sql)
```

but I am at a loss when it gets a bit more complex:

```
declare @sourcedatabase as varchar(max) = 'DATABASE1'
declare @targetdatabase as varchar(max) = 'DATABASE2'

declare @HighestID as int = (SELECT  max(Id) FROM @sourcedatabase.system.Organisationtype)
declare @i as int = (SELECT  max(Id) FROM @sourcedatabase.system.Organisationtype)

while @i >= (SELECT  min(Id) FROM @sourcedatabase.system.LaagTypeOrganisatie)
BEGIN
--SOME ACTIONS
set @i = @i + 1 
END 

declare @x as int = (select count(*) from @targetdatabase.sys.tables where name = @SomeNAME)

IF   @x <> 0
BEGIN
set @sql = 'DROP TABLE ' + @targetdatabase + '.' + @SomeNAME 
execute (@sql)
END
```

As you see I would like to have the database-naming variable.
Turning this whole script into one exec statement is quite complex and not very pretty to read.
Would it be an idea to read this script in a textfile, do a replace on @targetdatabase en @sourcedatabase and then execute it? If so, how would this be done?

I am looking forward to your ideas and contributions!

edit: the script is executed as a jobagent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't clear how you execute your script, but assuming that you're using either sqlcmd.exe or SSMS you can use [sqlcmd scripting variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188714.aspx) to substitute variables at runtime.